# NullPointerException on TextInputEditText

Tags: android

Whenever I am doing `onBackPressed()` and accessing the `editText`

```
private void saveValue() {
sp.edit().putString(KEY, editText.getText().toString().trim()).apply();
}
```

I am trying to access this from `onBackPressed()` in fragment like below

```
@Override
public boolean onBackPressed() {
   saveValue();
  return super.onBackPressed();
}
```

I am getting below exception in some of the devices based on Android 8.0 OS

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable 
androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.getText()' on a null object 
reference
```

Comment: where are you assigning this `editText`?

Comment: In your saveValue() check if your editText is null or initialize it like an empty String

Comment: editText is initialized by using butterknife, and it holds the view reference when user is doing any other action apart from onBackPressed(). Only in this case EditText value is null, and I am wondering how it is possible?

Comment: change that code from onbackpressed to onpause

Comment: when overriding events always nullcheck the activity/fragment and/or the accessed view. I Believe, somehow, the view/layout appended to that activity/fragment already gone

Comment: and check if you already made ButterKnife.unbind, or something similar, before that code